# How does the chain rule work in back propagation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, derivative

I'm studying neutral networks and I've come across a statement during the derivation of back propagation that I needed help for.

[image]

My question is if I were to cancel out the common factors in the second form, wouldn't the total sum to k times the original term? Is so, how is it a correct expansion?

PS: The formula was taken from http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com

Answer (score 0):

When you cancel out the common factors like you said, the k summation also gets canceled out.  Only the common factors sum across k and those get canceled out.